# script to shutdown server if no active users

Tags: linux, bash, users

I want to write a bash script that will run with cron every 5 minutes that will check if there's any active users logged in and if no active users are logged in, it will shutdown. 
I've come up with this:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                            
u=`users`;                                                                                                                             
l=${#u};                                                                                                                               
if [ $l -lt 2 ]                                                                                                                        
then                                                                                                                                   
        halt                                                                                                                           
fi
```

and was wondering if this will do it or if `users` will return something unexpected after the last one has disconnected.

**Additional information:**

I realized something else:
I just tried this out on an system at home running `Arch` and I got the following:

```
[ron@osboxes ~]$ users
[ron@osboxes ~]$ who
[ron@osboxes ~]$
```

how can this be? It's obvious that I'm an actively logged-on user, is it not?

Comment: write script that writes data to a log instead of shutting the server down ... then you can determine what `users` returns when the last user logs out

Answer (score 6):

It should be a comment but I don't have 50 rep point, so I will lose even more, post this comment as answer :)

If you run this script in every five min, your server could shutdown while booting in before you even able to login. So not a good idea.
Write a systemd timer.