# How to shutdown pc if no user is logged in?

Tags: linux, login, shutdown, timeout

I am sorry if I have missed any existing answers or solutions - my searching did not bring up any viable solutions yet.

**The issue:**

My pc contains Windows and Linux, with Linux being the primary OS.
Windows is used occasionally and has got the tendency of doing a reboot upon shutdown, to install some updates and then really shutdown.
However, as Linux is the primary boot target, this reboot-then-shutdown will boot into Linux, where it will sit at the logon indefinitely.
I want it to time out after 5 or 10 minutes of no login and shutdown.

**The solutions / attempts:**

I have come across [setting a timeout in /etc/systemd/login.conf](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716879/how-to-shutdown-pc-if-no-user-is-logged-in)

```
IdleAction=poweroff
IdleActionSec=10min
```

However, this kills my session after 10 minutes even if I am actively typing.

I have also found [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/563944/script-to-shutdown-server-if-no-active-users), about regularly checking if a user is logged in and then shutting down. Unfortunately, I have never written a bash script or set up systemd timers, which is why I am at a bit of a loss with this answer.

**My setup:** I am running Arch Linux, with the login being the console-based tty-login.

Thank you for any hints or recommendations.

Comment: If you login but do nothing, should that stop the idle timer? If you login and logout again, should that restart the idle timer?

Comment: If I log in, it should stop the timer. The only scenario I want to catch is when my pc reboots after a long Windows update phase and sits idly at the login. This usually happens when I try to shut it down in the evening, which means I only find out that it has been sitting there idly (with an active screen) the next day or day after.

Comment: Turn off Windows auto-update ? OK, my last (non-lamented) version was Win7 -- maybe you cannot do this any more.

Comment: The tricky part is that it's not Windows auto-update, where Windows would do a forced restart when it feels like it. Windows will download the update in the background and then use the user-initiated shutdown to install the update. This would be perfectly fine if Windows would not assume that it can reboot to finish the update. It's this reboot that boots the pc into Linux where it sits idly - if it would boot into Windows again, it would finish the update and shutdown properly.

Comment: Also consider Linux may be in the middle of some system background task (cron, systemd) that you do not want to break.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant It should be safe in almost all instances to shut down a Linux system, as long as you use the normal shutdown method (i.e. let your init manage the shutdown). Whatever is running in the background should be able to clean up if it needs to.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Wouldn't that apply to _any_ shutdown? I don't see how this situation is special in that regard.

Comment: @marcelm  True. Way down, I just feel this requirement could fall foul of the Law of Unintended Consequences.

Answer (score 5):

Create two systemd units and one script.

First unit:

```
/etc/systemd/system/are-users-logged.timer
[Unit]
Description=Start check for logged users

[Timer]
OnBootSec=15min
Unit=shutdown-ifno-logged-users
[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

runs `shutdown-ifno-logged-users.service` once after 15min from the boot.

Second unit:

```
/etc/systemd/system/shutdown-ifno-logged-users.service
[Unit]
Description=Shutdown if there are no logged users

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
ExecStart=script_to_check_logged_users
```

starts your script to check logged users.

In your script parse output of `loginctl --no-pager list-users` or maybe even `who -q` and shutdown if there is no user logged.

If you want to prevent reboot once somebody logged in and then logged out **before timer is triggered** you may try to stop `are-users-logged.timer` from `/etc/profile.d/somescript.sh` with something like `sudo systemctl stop are-users-logged.timer`. But i guess it is maybe problematic if user is not root due password asking.

Better create some file in /tmp with `echo` from `/etc/profile.d/somescript.sh` to indicate somebody was logged and check in your `script_to_check_logged_users` if it exists and skip shutdown.

Answer (score 4):

> I want it to time out after 5 or 10 minutes of no login and shutdown.

Maybe grub timeout feature satisfy you.

Add custom menuentry with halt command into the grub configuration and make it default. Set grub timeout to needed value. After poweron or reboot grub selects your default entry and turn off the computer after timeout if there is no user activity,

To boot any OS you need to select and boot menu entry manually.

For Arch add into `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`

```
menuentry "System shutdown" {
   echo "System shutting down..."
   halt
}
```

To change the default selected entry, edit `/etc/default/grub` and change the value of `GRUB_DEFAULT`:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT='System shutdown'
```

then

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Nice idea, I think this could work in a Grub environment. I am however using systemd-boot and don't want to use Grub. The shutdown should be triggered while the pc is waiting at the tty-login.